# Custom Marshalling of HashMap<String,Object> in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy, payara

I have a small problem regarding the marshalling via JAXB.

Currently I have a HashMap of Objects

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(HashMapAdapter.class)
private Map<String, Object> data;
```

beeing marshalled by the Custom HashMapAdapter

```
public class HashMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<HashMapAdapter.AdaptedMap, 
Map<String, Object>> {

@XmlRootElement
public static class AdaptedMap {

    @XmlVariableNode("key")
    List<Data> entries = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static class Data {

    @XmlTransient
    public String key;

    @XmlValue
    public Object value;

}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> unmarshal(AdaptedMap v) throws Exception {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

@Override
public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {
    AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.key = entry.getKey();
        data.value = entry.getValue();
        adaptedMap.entries.add(data);
    }
    return adaptedMap;
}
}
```

The Marshalling is based on the following Post: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html

The HashMap is filled with either Boolean, Long or String Values.

So regarding the Blog the expected JSON Output should be:

```
"data": {
    "booleanValue": true,
    "stringValue": "test",
    "longValue": 1234
}
```

But the real outcome is:

```
"data": {
    "longValue": {
        "type": "long",
        "value": 1234
    },
    "stringValue": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "test"
    },
    "booleanValue": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "value": true
    }
}
```

Im running on Payara Micro 174 and therefore on MOXy as JAXB provider.

Is it possible to get rid of the "type"/"value" nesting?

Best Regards

Simon

Comment: Hello @sbaeurle, you lack the '@XmlPath(".") on your map from your example, which is probably why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @DimpreJean-Sébastien Good Point, but that is not the Problem it works just fine when I'm using e.g. HashMap<String,Boolean>. The Problem is due the usage of Object as Generic.

Comment: Okay, i'm trying to think of a solution by using an adapter on your Object value. I'm pretty sure it should be possible but i can't wrap my head around it right now. I'll post an answer if i find something.

Comment: I thought of some kind of Adapter Solution too, but the Problem is you can only cover one kind of Object while leaving out the other two.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an MOxY implementation handy, could you try this and tell me if it works ?

```
public static class Data {

    @XmlTransient
    public String key;

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(type=Long.class),
        @XmlElement(type=String.class),
        @XmlElement(type=Boolean.class)
    })
    @XmlPath(".")
    public Object value;

}
```

EDIT :

The Output you get when using this Approach is:

```
"data": {
    "stringValue": {
        "value": test
    },
    "booleanValue": {
        "value": true
    },
    "longValue": {
        "value": 1234
    }
}
```

Sadly this differs a little from the expected.

Comment: The Problem with @XmlElements is, that you cannot get rid of the Object name so it fixes the Problem with the type nesting but you still have a slightly different Output

Comment: You would probably need somethins Like @XmlValues with a behaviour like XmlElements.